# Slave aapt time out

Tags: android

I've been having this error for a couple of days, and can't open any project or even create new ones. I didn't understand the solutions I found on internet, and I already reinstaled Android Studio, just to have the same error again. Please help me. I use Windows 10.

Edit: No I got this error:
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_5" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Fabiola\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds

Mine is at C:\User\Fabiola\SDKAndroidStudio\build-tools
Can it be a problem?

```
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_9" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Fabiola\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:122)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "png-cruncher_10" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Fabiola\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:122)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "png-cruncher_16" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Fabiola\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:122)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "png-cruncher_17" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Fabiola\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:122)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "png-cruncher_3" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Fabiola\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:122)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "png-cruncher_20" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Fabiola\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:122)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "png-cruncher_19" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Fabiola\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:122)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "png-cruncher_18" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Fabiola\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:122)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "png-cruncher_15" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Fabiola\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:122)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "png-cruncher_13" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Fabiola\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:122)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "png-cruncher_11" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Fabiola\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:122)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "png-cruncher_14" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Fabiola\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:122)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "png-cruncher_8" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Fabiola\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:122)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "png-cruncher_12" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Fabiola\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:122)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "png-cruncher_7" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Fabiola\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:122)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "png-cruncher_6" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Fabiola\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:122)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "png-cruncher_1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Fabiola\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:122)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "png-cruncher_2" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Fabiola\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:122)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "png-cruncher_4" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Fabiola\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:122)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "png-cruncher_5" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Fabiola\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:122)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 6):

- set the SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT environment variable to 30 in windows
- disable any running anti virus programs (i had symantec endpoint )
- Also i upgraded Android Studio to 2.x from an older version

These solved the same issue for me, hope it helps :)

Comment: This is not working for me. I have avast disabled it, disabled firewall(windows), set SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to 30, i have android studio3.x

Answer (score 1):

May be you were having problem with your Android-SDK files.

OR

As these Exception were saying:

```
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_18" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\Fabiola\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
```

that your application is not getting enough time to start or getting blocked during execution.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to modify the timeout on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Faced this issue in my MAC, added one env var for the same which worked like a charm for me.

Added this in my ~/.bash_profile

`export SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT=30`

Answer (score 0):

I tried setting `SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT` environment variable to `30` but it didn't help.

After further research, I manged to solve the error : `Exception in thread "png-cruncher_20" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds`  by re-installing compression library [**lib32z1**](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/lib32z1) using the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```